# Python Scrapy get the href url from the source code and export it to JSON File

Tags: python, json, csv, scrapy

I am new with python and Scrapy .I search the web but not found much example with Scrapy. as practice and challange , i try to get href link from the source code with Scrapy and put it into json file , I also found a helpful github source code to generate movie url from the source code using Scrapy and python . but unfortunately this [github](https://github.com/xldrx/kodi-persian-contents) source is out of date and not completely working. in the file name movie_spider.py I've made a single line change on the source code and replace url with recent working url , i mean i change:

```
name, start_urls = 'ip_spider', ['http://iranproud.com/movies']
```

to

```
name, start_urls = 'ip_spider', ['http://www.iranproud.vip/irani-best-movies']
```

and then i run it with this command:

```
scrapy crawl ip_spider -o movies_list.csv -t csv
```

currently movie.json has 237 movies but it's for 3 years ago and has not have all the recent movies. Does anybody can help me please what changes should or how should i update the [github](https://github.com/xldrx/kodi-persian-contents) `https://github.com/xldrx/kodi-persian-contents` in order to make it work...

here is part of the log:

```
2017-09-09 21:45:05 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://iranproud.net/site.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/iran-1-movies/tv&cinema/yek-damaghe-naghabel> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2017-09-09 21:45:05 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://iranproud.net/iran-1-movies/tv&cinema/az-ma-behtaroon> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2017-09-09 21:45:05 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://iranproud.net/site.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/iran-1-movies/tv&cinema/inja-aseman-hamishe-baranist> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2017-09-09 21:45:10 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://iranproud.net/iran-1-movies/tv&cinema/behtarin-hamsayeh-donya> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2017-09-09 21:45:10 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 137 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

here is the part of movies.json file (the result) , but it doesn't include all the recent movies url:

```
{"video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/KhastehNabashiHQ.mp4", "title": ["Khasteh Nabashid"]},
{"video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Khaneh_Neshin_HQ.mp4", "title": ["Khane Neshin"]},
```

Thanks.